# Linq IQueryable Generic Filter

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, c#-4.0

I am looking for a generic Filter for the searchText in the query of any Column/Field mapping

```
public static IQueryable<T> Filter<T>(this IQueryable<T> source, string searchTerm)
{
   var propNames = typeof(T).GetProperties(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public).Where(e=>e.PropertyType == typeof(String)).Select(x => x.Name).ToArray();


 //I am getting the property names but How can I create Expression for

 source.Where(Expression)
}
```

Here I am giving you an example scenario

Now From my HTML5 Table in Asp.net MVC4  , I have provided  a Search box to filter results of entered text , which can match any of the below columns/  Menu class Property values , and I want to do this search in Server side ,  how can I implement it.

**EF Model Class**

```
 public partial class Menu
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string MenuText { get; set; }
        public string ActionName { get; set; }
        public string ControllerName { get; set; }
        public string Icon { get; set; }
        public string ToolTip { get; set; }
        public int RoleId { get; set; }

        public virtual Role Role { get; set; }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
void Main()
{
   // creates a clause like 
   // select * from Menu where MenuText like '%ASD%' or ActionName like '%ASD%' or....
    var items = Menu.Filter("ASD").ToList();
}

// Define other methods and classes here
public static class QueryExtensions
{
    public static IQueryable<T> Filter<T>(this IQueryable<T> query, string search)    
    {           
        var properties = typeof(T).GetProperties().Where(p => 
                /*p.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(System.Data.Objects.DataClasses.EdmScalarPropertyAttribute),true).Any() && */
                p.PropertyType == typeof(String));        
        
        var predicate = PredicateBuilder.False<T>();
        foreach (var property in properties )
        {
           predicate = predicate.Or(CreateLike<T>(property,search));
        }
        return query.AsExpandable().Where(predicate);
    }
    private static Expression<Func<T,bool>> CreateLike<T>( PropertyInfo prop, string value)
    {       
        var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "f");
        var propertyAccess = Expression.MakeMemberAccess(parameter, prop);                    
        var like = Expression.Call(propertyAccess, "Contains", null, Expression.Constant(value,typeof(string)));

        return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(like, parameter);       
    }

}
```

You need to add reference to [LinqKit](http://www.nuget.org/packages/LinqKit) to use PredicateBuilder and AsExpandable method
otherwise won't work with EF, only with Linq to SQL

If you want `Col1 like '%ASD%' AND Col2 like '%ASD%' et`, change `PredicateBuilder.False` to `PredicateBuilder.True` and `predicate.Or` to `predicate.And`

Also you need to find a way to distinguish mapped properties by your own custom properties (defined in partial classes for example)

Comment: orPredicate  is not initilized is  it predicate only or differs like var  orPredicate = properties.Aggregate(predicate, (current, property) => current.Or(CreateLike<T>(property, search)));

Comment: sorry, typo, I'll change

Comment: Thank you very much , It's really helpful by the way How to ignore the case sensitivity  when using  Contains in expression

Comment: Welcome, I don't think is case sensitive, it depends on the server's collation.

Comment: Couldn't install LinqKit package "Binbin.Linq.PredicateBuilder" for .Net 4.6 framework

Answer (score 5):

You can use Expressions:

```
private static Expression<Func<T, bool>> GetColumnEquality<T>(string property, string term)
{
    var obj = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "obj");        

    var objProperty = Expression.PropertyOrField(obj, property);
    var objEquality = Expression.Equal(objProperty, Expression.Constant(term));

    var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(objEquality, obj);

    return lambda;
}

public static IQueryable<T> Filter<T>(IQueryable<T> source, string searchTerm)
{
    var propNames = typeof(T).GetProperties(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public)
                             .Where(e => e.PropertyType == typeof(string))
                             .Select(x => x.Name).ToList();

    var predicate = PredicateBuilder.False<T>();

    foreach(var name in propNames)
    {
        predicate = predicate.Or(GetColumnEquality<T>(name, searchTerm));
    }

    return source.Where(predicate);
}
```

Combined with the name [`PredicateBuilder`](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx) from C# in a NutShell. Which is also a part of [LinqKit](http://www.nuget.org/packages/LinqKit).

Example:

```
public class Foo
{
    public string Bar { get; set; }
    public string Qux { get; set; }
}

Filter<Foo>(Enumerable.Empty<Foo>().AsQueryable(), "Hello");

// Expression Generated by Predicate Builder
// f => ((False OrElse Invoke(obj => (obj.Bar == "Hello"), f)) OrElse Invoke(obj => (obj.Qux == "Hello"), f))
```